# C++ issue "cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [5]' to 'int'"

Tags: c++

New to c++ and I want to write a program like this:

> void fillArray(int ar[], int size, int inc);
>
> The function assumes the 0th element ar[0] is already filled with some value, and fills the remaining slots, from ar[1] on, with the value of the preceding element plus 'inc'. For instance, when ar[0] was filled with 5, ar[1] should be 8, ar[2] should be 11 and so on.
>
> I keep getting error"cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [5]' to 'int' ". How can I fix this and how can I finish my code? The outcome is like this:
>
> Enter the first value and increment for ar1: 4 3
>
> Enter the first value and increment for ar2: 5 2
>
> (1) ar1:
>   4 7 10 13 16

Following is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>   // to use rand(), srand() and RAND_MAX
#include <ctime>     // to use the library function time()
using namespace std;

//prototype
void fillArray(int,int,int);
void printArray(int,int);

int main()
{
srand(time(0));  // initialize random number generator

int x1,y1,x2,y2;
cout << "Enter the first value and increment for ar1: ";
cin >> x1, y1;
cout << "Enter the first value and increment for ar2: ";
cin >> x2, y2;

const int size = 5;
int ar1[size], ar2[size];

ar1[0] = x1, ar2[0] = x2;

cout << "(1) ar1:\n";
fillArray(ar1,size,y1);


system("pause");
return 0;

}
void fillArray(int ar[], int size, int inc)
{
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    ar[i] = ar[0] + inc;
    cout << ar[size];
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your prototype, that you initially declared:

```
void fillArray(int,int,int);
```

And this is your actual function, when the rubber hits road:

```
void fillArray(int ar[], int size, int inc)
```

Do you see the problem?

The prototype must match the function's signature, exactly. You should've written the prototype as:

```
void fillArray(int [],int,int);
```